# SQL getting datediff from same field

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I have a problem. I need to get the date difference in terms of hours in my table but the problem is it is saved in the same field. This is my table would look like.

```
  RecNo.    Employeeno   recorddate   recordtime    recordval
   1           001        8/22/2014      8:15 AM         1
   2           001        8/22/2014      5:00 PM         2
   3           001        8/24/2014      8:01 AM         1
   4           001        8/24/2014      5:01 PM         2
```

1 indicates time in and 2 indicates time out. Now, How will i get the number of hours worked for each day? What i want to get is something like this.

```
Date       hoursworked
8/22/2014       8
8/24/2014       8
```

I am using VS 2010 and SQL server 2005

Comment: what is your columns datatype and where do you want to do this, in SQL or VB?

Comment: `recno` `Empoloyeeno` are both nvarchar, `recorddate` `recordtime` are both datetime field and `recordval` is an integer. What I really want to do is the bottom example, extract the `date` and the `hoursworked`from the table above, save it to another table and produce a report from there.

Comment: what I've done so far is set a range `startdate' and `enddate` to loop through all the dates and call 2 SQL query; Query 1 is for the condition of `recordval`=1 and Query 2 is for the condition of `recordval` = 2 and from there get the `recordtime', but this method is a bit slow to execute. Getting the number of hours worked of 25 employees within a week is taking about 12 seconds to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You could self-join each "in" record with its corresponding "out" record and use [`datediff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to subtract them:

```
SELECT     time_in.employeeno AS "Employee No",
           time_in.recorddate AS "Date",
           DATEDIFF (hour, time_in.recordtime, time_out.recordtime) 
            AS "Hours Worked"
FROM       (SELECT *
            FROM   my_table
            WHERE  recordval = 1) time_in
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM   my_table
            WHERE  recordval = 2) time_out 
           ON time_in.employeeno = time_out.employeeno AND
              time_in.recorddate = time_out.recorddate
```

Comment: This assumes no shifts over midnight, a breaking case.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Seems to me the OP already assumes this, as there's no unique identifier for a shift. Unless you take the assumption that every "time_in" must be followed by a "time_out" and join on do something like join on `FLOOR(RecNo/2)`

Comment: If that was not OP's requirement the question is pretty simple isn't it? How many organizations are you aware of that pay an hourly wage instead of a salary and have absolutely no overnight shifts?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the late response. your query worked for me since I forgot to mention that there is also another type of recordval=3 for Over time-in and 4 for Over time out. So what I dis is just modify your query and worked great for me. and about shift running across midnight what i did is if time-out is negative i just add 24.  Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you always record time in and time out for every employee, and just one per day, using a self-join should work:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Employeeno, 
    t1.recorddate, 
    t1.recordtime AS [TimeIn], 
    t2.recordtime AS [TimeOut], 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,t1.recordtime, t2.recordtime) AS [HoursWorked]
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON 
    t1.Employeeno = t2.Employeeno 
    AND t1.recorddate = t2.recorddate 
WHERE t1.recordval = 1 AND t2.recordval = 2
```

I included the recordtime fields as time in, time out, if you don't want them just remove them.

Note that this datediff calculation gives 9 hours, and not 8 as you suggested.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88889/2)

Answer (score 0):

Using this sample data:

```
with table1 as (
    select * from ( values
         (1,'001', cast('20140822' as datetime),cast('08:15:00 am' as time),1)
        ,(2,'001', cast('20140822' as datetime),cast('05:00:00 pm' as time),2)

        ,(3,'001', cast('20140824' as datetime),cast('08:01:00 am' as time),1)
        ,(4,'001', cast('20140824' as datetime),cast('04:59:00 pm' as time),2)

        ,(5,'001', cast('20140825' as datetime),cast('10:01:00 pm' as time),1)
        ,(6,'001', cast('20140826' as datetime),cast('05:59:00 am' as time),2)
    )data(RecNo,EmployeeNo,recordDate,recordTime,recordVal)
)
```

this query

```
SELECT
     Employeeno
    ,convert(char(10),recorddate,120) as DateStart
    ,convert(char(5),cast(TimeIn as time))  as TimeIn
    ,convert(char(5),cast(TimeOut as time)) as TimeOut
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,timeIn, timeOut) / 60 AS [HoursWorked]
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,timeIn, timeOut) % 60 AS [MinutesWorked]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tIn.Employeeno, 
        tIn.recorddate, 
        dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,tIn.recordTime), tIn.recordDate)
             as TimeIn,             
        ( SELECT TOP 1 
             dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,tOut.recordTime), tOut.recordDate)
             as TimeOut
          FROM Table1 tOut
          WHERE tOut.RecordVal = 2
            AND tOut.EmployeeNo = tIn.EmployeeNo
            AND tOut.RecNo > tIn.RecNo
          ORDER BY tOut.EmployeeNo, tOut.RecNo
        ) as TimeOut
    FROM Table1 tIn
    WHERE tIn.recordval = 1
) T
```

yields (as desired)

```
Employeeno DateStart  TimeIn TimeOut HoursWorked MinutesWorked
---------- ---------- ------ ------- ----------- -------------
001        2014-08-22 08:15  17:00   8           45
001        2014-08-24 08:01  16:59   8           58
001        2014-08-25 22:01  05:59   7           58
```

No assumptions are made about shifts not running across midnight (see case 3).

This particular implementation may not be the most performant way to construct this correlated subquery, so if there is a performance problem come back and we can look at it again. However running those tests requires a large dataset which I don't feel like constructing just now.